# Unityにおける"But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found. "の対処法について

Tags: unity3d, unity2d, amazon-cognito

[マルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/134676)

以下のサイトを参考に、UnityでCognito UserPoolsを使って認証機能の実装を試みました。

[UnityでCognito UserPoolsを使ってサインアップ・サインインを実現する](https://dev.classmethod.jp/client-side/unity-client-side/unity-cognito-authentication/)

エディタ上のでテストは成功したのですが、ビルドしようとしたところAWSのdll関係でエラーが出ました。
そこで、シンプルに何も作っていない状態でAWSのSDKをインストールした状態でビルドしようとしたところ、同様に以下のエラーが出ました。
どうすればビルドできるようになるでしょうか？

```
ArgumentException: The Assembly Microsoft.CodeAnalysis is referenced by AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider.CodeAnalysis ('Assets/Packages/AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider.3.3.10.4/analyzers/dotnet/cs/AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider.CodeAnalysis.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] cache, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:154)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:194)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

何も作っていないUnityのファイルは以下です。
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RgTpXtdnHzYrHksz9lfjKJ5cnvbhDcVH

このファイルで行ったこと:

- Unityを新規作成
- NuGetをアセットストアからインストール
- AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider.3.3.10.4, AWSSDK.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication.0.9.4, AWSSDK.Core.3.3.24.3をNuGetからインストール
- 理想はAndroid向けにビルドすることなのでAndroid向けでビルド（ただしどのプラットフォームでもエラーがでる）

Answer (score 0):

[マルチポスト先の Teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/134676) で質問者本人が解決済みのようです。

> ビルドできました。
> `The Assembly 〇〇 is referenced by xx`
> の〇〇をNuGetから落とすか、そもそもそれを参照しているxxを削除すれば通りました。